# DROP Azure SQL Database using T-SQL in SSMS

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am unable to `DROP`  `Azure SQL Database` in `SSMS`

```
   DROP DATABASE xxxx
```

and getting this exception

```
Msg 42019, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
DROP DATABASE operation failed. Internal service error.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Comment: Do you get the error if you run only the `DROP DATABASE xxxx;` statement (without `IF EXISTS`)?

Comment: @DanGuzman I have edited my question and simplified the script with  just drop command and  error still occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connected to xxxx database you cannot perform drop database from within. You need to connect to master db and then perform `DROP DATABASE xxxx`.

> [DROP DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Azure SQL Database
>
> **You must be connected to the master database to drop a database.**
>
> The DROP DATABASE statement must be the only statement in a SQL batch and you can drop only one database at a time.

---

Second you should check if there is DELETE LOCK that prevents from dropping database.

[Lock resources to prevent unexpected changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources)

Comment: Thanks. if  sql script is executed by windows app or any other tool  then within script do i need something like 'USE master go then drop statement afterwards because within ssms i cannot apply 'use master statement however i can switch from ui drop down